# Database Design many tables VS generic table?

Tags: database-design, database-schema

We have a problem with our database design. We've had to break our customer contact information schema into  separate tables :
`Phone table,Email table, Fax table` etc and we then have a `many-to-many` relationship between the main `customer` table and the different contact tables.

For example  customers can have many phone numbers if the customer works in different locations and shares different bits of contact information with other customers. 
I am trying to decide between creating a generic table to hold all form of  contacts data in  and have lookup table for `contacts_types` field with tag values like `personal, email,work email,home phone ,cell phone, work phone , home fax ,work fax,work website etc`.

Which design would you advise?

Comment: Either way will work and either way will have benefits and drawbacks.  I think the question is valid, but as it's phrased, I believe it will incite debate over the "best" approach, and is therefore not constructiove per the site definition, which reads: *As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*

Comment: for me I am Junior developer and only developer on this Project because of that I'm trying to figure it out the best solution on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A person can have zero or more addresses, and an address can be used by zero or more people. The address assignment can change over time.

This is the correct answer:

```
Party -< PartyAddress >- Address

PartyAddress{
  partyId
  addressId
  fromDate
  toDate (nullable)
  label -> [work, home, fax, ...]
  extension (nullable)
}

TelephoneNumber : Address
EmailAddress : Address
WebSite : Address
MailingAddress : Address
```

It is useful to abstract address for sales order processing. That way you can fulfill an order to an email address if you want. Also makes it easy to "list all communication methods with this contact"

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has done database work for many years, create the separate tables. In the first place, eventually you may want different fields (I know our phone table and email table have different structures). In the second place the model you describe is an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) and it generally is a poor choice for both performance and data integrity (it becomes hard to enforce all the FKs you need).

I would never use an EAV table unless it was something so variable  (like the details of all the possible medical tests) that I had no other choice.

Answer (score 0):

To design such database you need to create many to many relationship with the table. You will need

Contact 
1 --- * Phone * --- 1 PhoneType
        1 --- * Email * --- 1 EmailType

If you need to share phone or email with other contact then:

Contact 
* --- * Phone * --- 1 PhoneType 
        * --- * Email * --- 1 EmailType

It's basic database design. I recommend you to read some example to give you more idea.

EDIT:
I found a simple diagram to help :
http://imar.spaanjaars.com/Images/Articles/N-LayerDesign/DatabaseDiagram.jpg

The complete example is there at the section "Design - Gathering Requirements"
http://imar.spaanjaars.com/416/building-layered-web-applications-with-microsoft-aspnet-20-part-1

You can add a PhoneType (Home Fax, Work Fax, Home Phone, etc) or EmailType (Home, Work) table if you want reference table.

Comment: Patrick, if you provide table structure then it will be easier for aelnajjar to understand.

Answer (score -1):

It reads like you need a 'contacts' table:

```
contact id
customer id
first name
surname
... other fields which would have only one value per contact
```

And also a phone table

```
contact id
phone number
phone type (home, office, mobile, fax)
```

Presumably the primary key of this table would be phone number, as this is supposed to be unique (the problem would be people entering false phone numbers)

I would think that each contact would have only one email address - whilst I have three addresses, one is for work, one is for home and one is for spam. In a work situation, I would only give my work email so this is the one to be stored in the 'contacts' table.

This schema allows you multiple contacts per customer, and multiple phone numbers per contact.